# ntdll.dll is not found in POCO?

Tags: c++, https, ntdll

When I use HTTPSClientSession to run a program, it crashes because:

```
NULL pointer: _pInstance [in file "c:\poco-1.4.3p1-all\util\include\poco\util\application.h,line 446]
```

Then, I traced the stack, and found that `ntdll.dll` was not loaded, which I doubted.

Any ideas why NTDLL looks like it's not loaded?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object  That POCO?

Comment: @Amigable Clark Kant,not what you said,it is POCO C++ library.

Comment: What makes you think NTDLL.DLL is not loaded?  Are you sure it's not just the symbols for NTDLL.DLL that aren't loaded?

Comment: @Paul Mitchell,I open the stack tracing in Debug mode in VS2005 and the last information displaying is that `NTDLL.DLL` is not found.
Of course,this maybe another reason,but I don't know.I just downloaded
`poco-1.4.3p1-all.zip` and `Win32OpenSSL-1_0_0j.exe`recommended in POCO home page,then I handle them step by step following the `README`.All is OK.However,When I try to run a sample with 
`POCO::NET::HTTPSClientSession` class ,it crashed with the error
`NULL pointer: _pInstance [in file "c:\poco-1.4.3p1-all\util\include\poco\util\application.h,line 446]`

Comment: I have solved this problem ,because of a instance of Application didn't be construct.Then ,I want to know : how to use `POCO::NET::HTTPSClientSession` correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem ,because of a instance of Application didn't be construct